# If I know nothing about the odds of two events, should I assume their odds are 50/50?

Tags: probability

Not a mathematician so this is an amateur question.

Let's say I am arguing about a friend; I point to some small piece of evidence that says the odds of events a and b are 10/90. However, he notes that there are lots of reasons to be uncertain about this event; that the conditions behind the previous evidence are also uncertain. Is he reasonable to bet on a 50/50 chance? Or is it just as reasonable to bet on any odds (say 1/100)?

As certainty decreases, should my expectation of an event with two possible outcomes go to 50%?

Comment: Either you win the lottery next week or you do not, and there's some small piece of evidence saying the odds of winning are pretty low, but there's some uncertainty about how this is measured.  Without further information, will you just assume equal likelihood of these outcomes?

Comment: But there's a lot of a priori knowledge about lotteries. I'm talking about an event for which the only a priori knowledge is that 1/10 tidbit and that it's very fuzzy.

Comment: the most "reasonable" approach is to agree that you do not have enough elements to make a "statistic" judgement.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a big box which we know contains many colored balls. We know the balls are either red or blue, but we do not know how many of each there are. We can take balls from the box but we cannot see the color of a ball until it has been taken.

Given this knowledge, it seems reasonable to assign $50/50$ odds to the statement that the next ball we take from the box will be red.

Now we take a ball and observe that it is red. We put the ball back in, shake the box well, and take a ball again. This time the ball is blue. We repeat this process several times. After a while we notice that we have taken balls from the box ten times, and only once did we get a red ball.

That suggests the odds of drawing a red ball are $10/90.$ But this evidence is very uncertain; it could easily be the case that the odds are greater or less and we just by luck got more or fewer red balls than expected.

The odds could even be $50/50$ after all. But in these circumstances I think reasonable people would bet on there being a much less than $50\%$ chance to get a red ball each time. The $50/50$ bet really does not seem wise.

The answer for your particular question may depend on what reason there is to assign $50/50$ odds a priori, and what kind of evidence there is for $10/90$ odds.